# Sagepay (Magenest) - 500 errors when 3d Secure is active

Tags: magento2, checkout, sagepay, 3d-secure

Hoping someone can help, since we've tried absolutely everything to reproduce and fix this issue, but we're unable to. I'd really love for someone UK based to weigh in here because we're at our wits end.

Our client has recently started reporting that some of their customers are unable to complete their order when paying by SagePay.

We checked out the error log and we discovered this error:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/Magenest/SagePay/Controller/Direct/PostBack.php:65

{closure}
(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#4 /var...\n', referer: https://secure7.arcot.com/acspage/cap?RID=1111&VAA=A
```

The line in question:

`$payment = $order->getPayment();`

Looking into the access log, it looks like all these customers reach this 3D secure page and then get a 500 error. Refreshing the page returns them to checkout. The only thing all these customers have in common is the fact that they're using Chrome (on both desktop and android). Literally there's nothing else tying them together.

The order does get created, but stays at pending (instead of complete). In their SagePay terminal, the transaction is registered, but cancelled because it's awaiting completion and thus expires after 15 minutes.

We've turned off 3D secure checking from the SagePay admin and that seems to have solved the issue, but that's not ideal because the client has to pay to process unsecure transactions.

I would also like to stress this **isn't all 3D secure transactions** - we've tried this with 3d secure both using Monzo and Barclaycard and they were successful.

So here are the specifics:

- Magento 2.3.2 store
- MageNest SagePay extension
- PHP 7.2

So it's a mighty weird one for sure. I appreciate it's a very specific issue, but if anyone has any experience with getData() issues on the checkout (specifically if it's for 3d secure) then I would be most grateful.

But like I say, we cannot reproduce this no matter what. That's the most frustrating part.

We've contacted the plugin vendors, who are unable to help to a degree because we can't grant them SSH access.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Literally as soon as I posted this, a colleague of mine told me that they had this on a similar (non-Magento) project - it's related to a recent Chrome update:

> Google Chrome recently started rolling out changes to prevent cookies
> being sent to websites when users are redirected from one website to
> another. This impacts the 3d Secure process as users are shown the
> merchant 3ds page via an iFrame, once payment is complete the iFrame
> redirects users back to the website. The website then instructs the
> parent window payment is taken & redirects to the confirmation page.

> The issue is, when users are redirected from the merchant 3ds page
> back to the site, despite the booking cookie being present, Chrome
> does not send it. This results in failed payment processing as the
> website is unable to correlate the payment with an order

Fingers crossed MageNest will be able to provide an upgrade.

I hope this helps others in this pickle.